# Display string "00264A7BC" as "00 264 A7 BC"

Tags: c#

I have the string `"00264A7BC"` and I would like to display it as `"00 264 A7 BC"`.

So, 2 letters + space + 3 letters + space + 2 letters + space + 2 letters.

I was trying `ToString` but it seems it does not have such an option.

How can I do this?

Comment: combining  `string.Substring`s is not enough?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the format is strict you can use `String.Substring` and `String.Format`(for readability):

```
string result = string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}"
                             , str.Substring(0, 2)
                             , str.Substring(2, 3)
                             , str.Substring(5, 2)
                             , str.Substring(7));
```

If you want a cryptic but safe LINQ approach:

```
var whiteSpaces = new HashSet<int>{ 2, 5, 7};
result = string.Join("", str
    .Select((c, i) => whiteSpaces.Contains(i) ? " " + c : c.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex:

```
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"(\w\w)(\w\w\w)(\w\w)(\w\w)", "$1 $2 $3 $4");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this...

```
string newString = string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}",
    new string(originalString.Take(2).ToArray()),
    new string(originalString.Skip(2).Take(3).ToArray()),
    new string(originalString.Skip(5).Take(2).ToArray()),
    new string(originalString.Skip(7).Take(2).ToArray()));
```

Edited: Modified for correct syntax.

Comment: Result: `System.Linq.Enumerable+<TakeIterator>d__3a1[System.Char] System.Linq.Enumerable+<TakeIterator>d__3a1[System.Char] System.Linq.Enumerable+<TakeIterator>d__3a1[System.Char] System.Linq.Enumerable+<TakeIterator>d__3a1[System.Char]`

Comment: Yes, forgot to do a new string on them.  Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought that judicious use of string splicing was the way forward: i.e. don't try to be clever. Maybe even simply:

```
int i=0, j=0;
str[i++] = orig[j++];
str[i++] = orig[j++];
str[i++] = ' ';
str[i++] = orig[j++];
str[i++] = orig[j++];
str[i++] = orig[j++];
str[i++] = ' ';
str[i++] = orig[j++];
str[i++] = orig[j++];
str[i++] = ' ';
str[i++] = orig[j++];
str[i++] = orig[j++];
```